# selecting value from a programmatically created combobox in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

I have created a series of comboboxes within a panel, and I have no difficulty populating each of these comboboxes with the correct values from my database, but I can't extract (put in a variable) the value that I select when clicking on any of the comboboxes. I have tried several things to no avail. I looked into a solution proposed by somebody on another site which used lists, but that either does not apply to my problem, or I did not understand it. Any help would be appreciated. I've been struggling with this for weeks. Thanks a lot!

This is the relevant part of my code:

```vb
Private Sub llenaPanelKeywords()

      Try

            combokywrd = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
            combokywrd.Left = kywrdLabel.Left + kywrdLabel.Width + 1
            combokywrd.Top = 10 + SaltoDeFilaKeywords * 30 
            combokywrd.Width = 81
            combokywrd.Height = 25
            combokywrd.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))

            PanelKywrds.Controls.Add(combokywrd)

            combokywrd.Name = kwDataTable.Rows(kwRowPosition)("IdKeyword").ToString()

            'the combo gets populated only upon clicking on it:
            AddHandler combokywrd.Click, AddressOf combokywrd_click

        SaltoDeFilaKeywords = SaltoDeFilaKeywords + 1

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("falla en llenar panel keywords " & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub combokywrd_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combokywrd.Click

    Try

        Dim combokywrd As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)

        idKeywordSelect = combokywrd.Name.ToString()

                    combokywrd.DataSource = Nothing 'por alguna razón antes de poner esto, fallaba al llenar uno de los combos, pero no los demás (largo total)

        combokywrd.Items.Clear()

        Dim stringSQLValorKywrd = "SELECT DISTINCT valorKeyword FROM [TOOLTOWERDbase].[dbo].[articuloKeyword] WHERE idKeyword = " & idKeywordSelect 


        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(stringSQLValorKywrd, con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dtVK As New DataTable()
        sda.Fill(dtVK)

        combokywrd.DataSource = dtVK
        combokywrd.DisplayMember = "valorkeyword"
        lstCombos.Add(combokywrd)


        combokywrd.Tag = combokywrd.Name

        AddHandler (combokywrd.SelectedValueChanged), AddressOf combokywrd_SelectedValueChanged 

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("carga valoresKeyword falló " & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub combokywrd_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combokywrd.SelectedValueChanged

    'I cannot go beyond populating the comboboxes:
    'I have tried with selectedindexchanged as well


    MessageBox.Show(combokywrd.SelectedText.ToString()) 'shows blank

    Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)

    MsgBox(cb.SelectedValue.ToString()) 'shows System.Data.DataRowView

    MsgBox("combobox’s tag: " & cb.Tag.ToString()) 'it shows the correct tag

    Dim tempString = combokywrd.Items(combokywrd.SelectedValue).ToString  'value of ‘0’ is not valid for index

End Sub
```

Comment: `SelectedText` is probably not what you think it is.  The event is `SelectedValueChanged` so try examining `SelectedValue`

Comment: @Plutonix: Shouldn't have had SelectedText there, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox(cb.SelectedValue.ToString()) 'shows System.Data.DataRowView
```

You're getting the value, but you didn't put a string in the combo box, you put a whole row in there.  (Because you bound to a table, not to a list.)  Try cb.SelectedValue[0].ToString(), if that doesn't work, put a breakpoint on the line, go to the immediate window (ctrl+g), type cb.SelectedValue. and see what options come up after the second ".", you'll find something there to let you get the wanted field of the row instead of the whole row.

Comment: putting a zero withing parenthesis did the trick. Thank you very much. I'm now getting another error, though; namely when I try to change my selection from the combobox, I get the error "Object Variable Or With Block Variable Not Set Error". I assume I need to reset something, but I haven't figured out what.